# help identify the part number from the marking of SOT-23 components

Tags: transistors, analog, components, surface-mount, component-selection

I want to figure out the part number of the following components all (SOT-23) from a 20 year old PCB i am trying to fix , it is coated with conformal coating , but i scratched the top of these components :

The strange is the vertical letter along with the horizontal marking . this is how i Read them :

**1. U1 K**

[image: U1 K ?]

**2. Z1 C**

[image: Z1 C ?]

**3. O2p 45**

[image: OPS]

**4. JSs 42**

[image: jsc]

**5. Sts 3N**

[image: sts]

Comment: Basically impossible. Imagine finding a part number for a resistor just by having one of the colour bands. But you don't even know which one.

Comment: Some context is often useful. You can narrow down the search a lot if you know that this one is probably a NPN BJT and that one could be a linear regulator or whatever.

Comment: @brhans , they are either diodes or transistors , according to the circuit and traces in the PCB . now i will assume they are NPN and start digging , then PNP , then DIOdes etc....  but how do i start ? i donot know which company made them , so assume NPN where should i search ? is there a naming standard ?

Comment: @PlasmaHH , so what do you propose in such case ? what do people usually do , excuse my noob question

Comment: Kind of reverse engineer the section of the circuit you are interested in.

Comment: Need some detailed overall shots of the PCB the are on to get context. What is the device? what is it's function?

Comment: But if it is 20 years old, trying to identify them will be a near impossible task as there were more factions as it were in the semi industry (nowadays the companies merge together), and datasheets are far less commonly available due to the fact the internet practically didn't exist back then to the extent it does today.

Comment: @TomCarpenter that is my fear !! how ever i will try my best

Comment: i can now confirm that according to the circuit Z1 C , is a zener diode , i will try to find out which one it is from this link :http://www.s-manuals.com/smd/z1

Comment: locate a service manual, test known good devices, reverse engineer the schematic and look what makes sense, apply all the experience

Answer (score 2):

You could desolder each, one-by-one, and run them through a good [tester](https://www.google.com/search?q=transistor+lcr+tester) to uncover what type of device they are and their pinouts. Some testers even report beta, handle mosfets, etc. Even with this knowledge you'll still have to reverse the circuitry to find modern devices which suit it.

To get the conformal coating off, [Pace](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vpgMn88Qfjs) has a helpful video.

Answer (score 1):

Most devices of this vintage used 'industry standard' bipolar parts, and the circuits usually followed popular design practices (often being almost direct copies of text book or datasheet examples). The prototype design may have used through-hole parts, then smd equivalents were chosen for the production version. Exact part numbers may not be important because other manufacturer's equivalents would often be substituted due to availability and cost issues.

The first step in repairing a circuit is to understand how it is meant to work, so you need at least a partial circuit diagram. If this not available then you should trace it out. Use a multimeter on continuity test to find where each trace goes. Use diode test to measure between all terminals of each part to determine if it is NPN/PNP/FET/diode etc. If you are still unsure about a part then remove it from the board and test it separately, or power the board up and measure voltages across it.

Once you have determined the *function* of each part you can decide whether you need to know its exact specifications (most of the time you don't) or the actual part number so you can replace a faulty part with its closest equivalent.

Compare the markings (in datasheets or Google image search) of known parts. 
Letters rotated 90º may be batch codes that can be ignored. Sometimes the first/last character is a prefix/suffix, so for example "O2p" might be an FMMT2222 (equivalent to 2N2222).

Comment: this was helpful , now i am able to determine 4 of them